# Ionic Notification app Icon Issue

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm building an ionic app using ionic 3.2, the big issue I'm facing is fcm notification icon. I'm using fcm-node library for sending notification from my server. I tried to figure out from the past questions and applied all including:

```
notification: {
    title: title,
    body: messagetosend,
    sound: "default",
    icon: 'icon',
    click_action: "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
}
```

and adding icon.png in res/drawable folder. Also tried with 96 * 96 size having transparent background but I'm just getting the android default icon as notification icon.

Here are my android platform configurations from config.xml file:

```
<platform name="android">
   <allow-intent href="market:*" />
   <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
   <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
   <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
   <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
```

This is my app icon:

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Can you please confirm you have icon with 72*72?

Comment: Yes. Also tried using 72 * 72 icon.

Comment: Which os version you are testing notification?

Comment: tried on Lollipop, Nougat and Oreo as well.